# How to count number of times a specific value occurs in Pivot Table?

Tags: excel

I have following table:
[image: Excel Table]

I want to create pivot table that would count for each of groups the number of Review & Re-review. Something that would look like this:

[image: Desired excel table]

I need to do it as pivot table because I want to be able to catch proper data after a double click.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried to split "Kind of task" column in to two: Review & Re-review. That gives me proper pivot table output, but when I want double click on a cell to provide me input data I have data for overall "Kind of task" not for specific "Kind of task".

Example, what I've got after clicking cell under Re-review in Category A row:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand. Doesn't a simple Pivot Table with *Group* in the Rows field, *Kind of task* in the Columns field and *Group* in the Values field (set to Count) give you what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to duplicate your issue. If you put Category in rows, Kind of task in columns, and count the number of Names, you get an output similar to yours (total is wrong direction). From there, double-clicking on `reriew` for `category a` does return the screenshot you indicated you wanted.

Check your pivot settings against this [Sample spreadsheet.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9hK0gzcK7mLJoCz8DFw?e=vwNblL)